# How to get response from FB page like in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular5, facebook-like

I am using ngx-facebook for implement FB page like. I want to know if my FB page was liked or not to perform some action on basis of response.

I followed "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-facebook" tutorial to implement FB like.

Comment: important question: what actions exactly? what´s the use case for knowing if your page was liked?

Comment: @luschn I want to capture info if page is liked and if it is liked then I am giving them some credits.

Comment: ok, that´s why the question was so important, i will generate an answer

Answer (score 1):

Rewarding users in any way for liking a Page is not allowed. The only way to know if a user liked a Page is to authorize that user with the `user_likes` permission. After that, you can check if the Page is liked. You will not get that permission approved by Facebook though, if you reward users for liking, or gate content behind likes.

TL;DR: It´s not possible and not allowed for your use case.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.4